# Pass a list of components as input to another component

Tags: angular

I would like to a pure UI component that can show a grid of other UI components, but the grid UI component must/can not know of the types of the other UI components it has to show in its grid, they can be anything (but of course always a Angular component).

How can I do this? What property type can I use in my grid component to hold a list of totally unknown components? And how do I display the components in the list in my grid layout?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could make use of inheritance here.

Create a BaseComponent from where the components members of your grid inherit, and then, in the grid component you can declare an array of BaseComponent[].

Depending on what you want to do next with those members, you need to add them to the entryComponents[] in your module. You can read more about dynamic components here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You got me on track here. I now have a base component and a array of those in my component (@Input() cards: CardComponent[];), but how do I render them in my template? My template has (<ListView [items]="cards">), but how do I render each component inside this list?